# Polya's distribution in Durret's Probability Theory book: A typo?

Tags: probability-theory

In Durret's book there's this theorem.
[image: Theorem]

But then in an example later in the book, we find the following.

[image]

I think this is a typo, where the density has been switched with the Ch.f.

However, we later find a restatement of that in the remark below...

[image]

So, what am I not understanding? Is this correct, and why?

Comment: What makes you think it is a typo? Everything looks correct to me.

Comment: @MikeEarnest in the theorem the density is outside the integral, and inside it's the ch.f.  However, in the example, he switched them

Comment: After that equation, he writes "let $s=x,y=-t$." When you do so, the integral becomes the definition of $E[e^{itX}]$, where $X$ has density $(1-\cos x)/\pi x^2$. This proves the characteristic function of $X$ is $(1-|t|)^+$, as claimed.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I'm not sure I'm following you. You're saying that using just the definition of ch.f. we get the equality? Then what's the point of using the theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to break out my copy of Durret for this, you left out a very important paragraph. Right before Example 3.3.8, he says

> Applying the inversion formula Theorem 3.3.5 to the ch.f. in Examples 3.3.5 and...

Look at Example 3.3.5. It is the "triangular distribution," whose density is $(1-|x|)^+$ and ch.f. is $2(1-\cos t)/t^2$. Apply Theorem 3.3.5 to that, and the result is the equation claimed.

Comment: I get it now! Thanks ;)

Comment: +1 for your (exact) 15k ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Haha thnx, I am aesthetically pleased